# Applescript to create folders and download files from weblink to those created folders based on .CSV values

Tags: applescript

In my example .CSV file, I have a column A with the following values: 2,2,5,5,5. In column B are hyperlinks to corresponding files that require downloading: http://example.com/2A.pdf, http://example.com/2B.pdf, http://example.com/5A.pdf, http://example.com/5B.pdf, http://example.com/5BC.pdf. Having difficulty creating an applescript that creates the DL folder (based on the non-unique column A value) and applies the DLs of any corresponding row to the appropriate folder. Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA.

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I am assuming the CSV file looks something like this:

```
2, http://example.com/2A.pdf
2, http://example.com/2B.pdf
5, http://example.com/5A.pdf
5, http://example.com/5B.pdf
5, http://example.com/5BC.pdf
```

and that the file *2A.pdf* should end up in a directory called *2*.

Assuming I have interpreted this correctly, here is the AppleScript that will achieve this (replace */Path/To/Save/Folder/* with the full path to the folder where these new files and folders will be downloaded, and */Path/To/File.csv* to the full path of the CSV file):

```
    -- Note: The ending / is essential in BaseDir
    set BaseDir to POSIX file "/Path/To/Save/Folder/"
    set rows to every paragraph of (read "/Path/To/File.csv")

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"/"}

    set [TopDir, BaseFolder] to [text items 1 thru -3, text item -2] of ¬
        POSIX path of BaseDir


    -- Create initial base folder if it doesn't exist
    tell application "Finder" to if not (exists BaseDir) then ¬
        make new folder in (TopDir as text as POSIX file) ¬
        with properties {name:BaseFolder}

    -- This will prevent EOF-related errors
    -- Thanks to @user3439894 for highlighting the need for this
    set rows to reverse of rows
    if the number of words of the first item in rows is 0 ¬
        then set rows to the rest of rows

    repeat with row in rows

        set [N, |url|] to [first word, text items -2 thru -1] of row

        -- Create folder into which file will be downloaded
        tell application "Finder" to if not (exists [BaseDir, N] as text) then ¬
            make new folder in BaseDir with properties {name:N}

        -- This is the shell command that downloads the file
        -- e.g. "cd '/Users/CK/Desktop/example.com/5'; curl example.com/5BC.pdf \
        --       remote-name --silent --show-error"
        set command to ("cd " & ¬
            quoted form of POSIX path of ([BaseDir, N] as text) & ¬
            "; curl " & |url| as text) & ¬
            " --remote-name --silent --show-error"

        -- Run the shell command
        do shell script command

    end repeat

    -- Open folder in Finder upon completion of downloads
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        open BaseDir
    end tell
```

I should highlight that this is **not** a robust script intended for general use that would work across situations, but rather an **example** script that is tailored specifically to the case described.  If your CSV file differs even slightly from my assumed format, errors are likely to occur.

Comment: Did you test your code before posting it? It's a nice script and I'd +1 if it had worked. The primary issue is a missing `/` in `command` when `do shell script command` is executed. The secondary issue is failing when the file has a _newline_ (`0A`) at the end, which is quite normal and should always be tested for when looping through the lines of a file. (It will also fail with an empty line within the lines of the file.) Also, it's generally accepted that if one changes `AppleScript's text item delimiters` that they be reset at the point in the script the change is no longer applicable.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for highlighting the missing "/".  This error got thrown because I copied the code from *Script Editor* into *Safari* and, in substituting my test folder for the dummy declaration */Path/To/Save/Folder/*, forgot the ending "/".  Regarding the potential EOF problem, this is one of those telltale signs that I'm still a novice at this.  It would not have occurred to me had you not said it.  I've added a couple of lines to catch this, so thanks again.  Lastly, I intentionally choose not to reset the TIDs so will keep this as it is for now, which is common across all my scripts.